# How to loop through a string and get the character in each position (some with accents) with the accents not sepparated?

Tags: javascript, utf-8, compare, ascii, utf-16

I have to get the amount of accents of each character on a string, so I'm looping through the characters of the text of a `<h2>` tag with `contenteditable= true`, I can't compare some accentuated characters with the characters in the Accents DB because they get split into the character and the accent, but some other accentuated characters are treated as one character.

```js
let Accents= { 
    /*...*/
    'x': [
            ["x", 0], 
            ["́x́", 1], 
            ["̂x̂", 2], 
            ["ẍ", 2], 
            ["̌x̌", 2], 
            ["ẋ", 1], 
            ["̧x̧", 1], //
            ["̱x̱", 1], 
            ["̣x̣", 1], 
            ["ᶍ", 2] 
        ],
     /*...*/
}

$("button").on("click", function(){
  text= $(".text").text()
  for(e in text){
    console.log(text[e])
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2 class= "text" contenteditable= "true">Lorem Ipx́um ẋ</h2>
<button>Log each character</button>
```

How can I get `x́` on the logs as with `ẋ`?, I need to do this in order to compare with the characters in the Accents DB. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't… [Unicode Normalization Forms](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/) could help however the only *accented* `x`s in recent Unicode database are - `ᶍ` (U+1D8D,  *Latin Small Letter X With Palatal Hook*)
- `ẋ` (U+1E8B,  *Latin Small Letter X With Dot Above*)
- `ẍ` (U+1E8D,  *Latin Small Letter X With Diaeresis*)
- `ꭖ` (U+AB56,  *LATIN SMALL LETTER X WITH LOW RIGHT RING*)
- `ꭗ` (U+AB57,  *LATIN SMALL LETTER X WITH LONG LEFT LEG*)
- `ꭘ` (U+AB58,  *LATIN SMALL LETTER X WITH LONG LEFT LEG AND LOW RIGHT RING*)
- `ꭙ` (U+AB59,  *LATIN SMALL LETTER X WITH LONG LEFT LEG WITH SERIF*)

Comment: This is useful, I can't upvote any more comments for today, so I'll upvote your comment tomorrow

Comment: Also, if I do this: text= $(".text").text().normalize("NFC") it doesn't work either, any other ideas?